# Why does MySQL force the tradeoff between swallowing errors and leaking commits in transactions?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transaction

Referring specifically to the choice of whether to use `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION`.  If you use it, you swallow errors [and there doesn't seem to be any way to access them programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858567/mysql-exception-handler-access-exception-being-handled), at least up to 5.5.  If you don't use it, [you leak transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896479/what-happens-if-you-dont-commit-transaction-in-a-database-say-sql-server), and drivers such as JDBC auto-commit them instead of aborting them.

What gives?  This sounds...  awful.